# Reorder divs place with PHP request

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I just wanna ask you how is the order in system that will allow me to

```
first get data -> animated (remove old divs) -> 
and put new to old's place.
```

Imagine a php request to database (maybe ajax), lets say online shop and user wanna order a products by price. When this happens my request will be to get first data from database and order it by size, then i wanna remove old divs (by default that i show on page) and repalce them with new ones with containing information. I think a little jquery help will be gr8 here.

Thanks!

Comment: You can do it by ajax. What's your question?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with PHP or MySQL. What you are looking for is the most classic use for ajax request: dynamically updating part of the page. The internet is full of examples of how to do this.

Have a look at the jQuery .load() method for the easiest possible example: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read this perfect article about ajax in jquery:
[5 Ways to Make Ajax Calls with jQuery](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/)

- **load()**: Load a piece of html into a container DOM.
- **$.getJSON()**: Load a JSON with GET method.
- **$.getScript()**: Load a JavaScript.
- **$.get()**: Use this if you want to make a GET call and play extensively with the response.
- **$.post()**: Use this if you want to make a POST call and don’t want to load the response to some container DOM.
- **$.ajax()**: Use this if you need to do something when XHR fails, or you need to specify ajax options (e.g. cache: true) on the fly.